# Indentation problems in if-elif statements

Tags: python, if-statement, tabs, python-requests, indentation

I have an indentation error:

```
age = 3
if age > 0:
    print("0")
elif age < 0:
```

Returns

> SyntaxError: unindent does not match indetation level

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)
[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ... 
[You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: In a shell, after a carriage-return, try a backspace to *un-indent* and let the shell handle it.

Comment: Placed the picture instead of a link to the picture. Also added code

Answer (score 0):

Don't add spaces yourself. The `>>>` takes up space but isn't actual indentation. So it should look like below.

```
>>> if age>0:
    print ("O")
elif age<0:
```

Comment: Python is an indentation based language. I suggest you to use Pycharm IDE(You can download the community edition) or any other IDE of your choice as a beginner otherwise it is really frustrating specially when you are coming from a language where indentation is not required like c,java etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Must go back to the previous 4 blocks